# django class based view get_context_data got an unexpected keyword arguement

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-class-based-views

I am trying to do a CRUD application from django class based views. 
Here is my view to update/create a note.

```
class CreateNoteView(CreateView):

    model = Note
    template_name = 'edit_note.html'

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('notes-list')

    def get_context_data(self):

        context = super(CreateNoteView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['action'] = reverse('notes-create')
        return context


class UpdateNoteView(UpdateView):

    model = Note
    template_name = 'edit_note.html'

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('notes-list')

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):

        context = super(UpdateNoteView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['action'] = reverse('notes-edit',
                                    kwargs={'pk':self.get_object().id})
        return context
```

Here is my models file:

```
# Create your models here.
class Note(models.Model):

    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.TextField()
    pub_date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
```

My urls file looks like this:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
       url(r'^create/$',CreateNoteView.as_view(), name='notes-create',),
       url(r'^$', ListNoteView.as_view(), name='notes-list',),    
       url(r'^edit/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', UpdateNoteView.as_view(), name='notes-edit',),                       
)
```

and the template is as follows:

```
{% if note.id %}
<h1> Edit Note </h1>
{% else %}
<h1>Add Notes</h1>
{% endif %}

<form action="{{ action }}" method="POST">
  {% csrf_token %}
  <ul>
    {{ form.as_p }}
  </ul>
  <input type="submit" value="Save" />
</form>
<a href="{% url "notes-list" %}">back to list</a>
```

I am getting an error,

**Exception Type: TypeError at /create/**

**Exception Value: get_context_data() got an unexpected keyword argument 'form'**

Here is the traceback:

```
File "/home/.virtualenvs/djtalk/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  115.                         response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/home/.virtualenvs/djtalk/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in view
  68.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/.virtualenvs/djtalk/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in dispatch
  86.         return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/.virtualenvs/djtalk/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/edit.py" in get
  195.         return super(BaseCreateView, self).get(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/.virtualenvs/djtalk/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/edit.py" in get
  155.         return self.render_to_response(self.get_context_data(form=form))

Exception Type: TypeError at /create/
Exception Value: get_context_data() got an unexpected keyword argument 'form'
```

Comment: Can you show us the code for `CreateNoteView`? It's likely that you're redefining `get_context_data` there, and do not have the `**kwargs` argument for it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Update

```
def get_context_data(self):
```

in `CreateNoteView` to:

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
```

---

When you are overriding a method (in this case: `get_context_data`), you should make sure that you keep the same signature if possible: in this case, `get_context_data` is expected to receive `self, **kwargs`.

---

Regarding your comment:

```
class NoteMixin(object):

    model = Note
    template_name = 'edit_note.html'

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('notes-list')

     def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(NoteMixin, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['action'] = self.get_action()
        return context

class UpdateNoteView(NoteMixin, UpdateView):
    def get_action(self):
        return reverse('notes-edit', kwargs={'pk':self.get_object().id})

class CreateNoteView(NoteMixin, CreateView):
    def get_action(self):
        return reverse('notes-create')
```

Comment: this question is slightly tangential, but could you please show me how to inherit the `CreateNoteView` and `UpdateNoteView` from a base class, to prevent repetition?

Comment: doing this gives me an error - `AttributeError: Generic detail view CreateNoteView must be called with either an object pk or a slug.`

Comment: i think the trouble is arising because, `CreateNoteView` is inheriting from `CreateView` and `UpdateNoteView` is inheriting from `UpdateView` so the `NoteMixin` should not inherit from `UpdateView`, if not *UpdateView* then what should it inherit from?

Comment: @user1629366 Yeah, sorry, `NoteMixin` should only inherit from `object`. Bad, bad copypasting!

Comment: @JosueTtito Thanks for the edit here. There was indeed an error. Not sure why it got rejected.

Answer (score 1):

Check your CreateNoteView.get_context_data function signature - /create/ maps to your CreateNoteView in your urls.py